# Lutris can't find Vulkan after brew install shared-mime-info

Tags: linux, vulkan, wine

Everything was working fine until I ran `brew install shared-mime-info` now Lutris responds with the following when I try to launch it along with a prompt to install drivers even though I've already completed the steps [here](https://github.com/lutris/docs/blob/master/InstallingDrivers.md)

```
2022-09-16 00:20:09,461: Starting Lutris 0.5.10.1
2022-09-16 00:20:09,488: No folder at /home/dan/.local/share/lutris/runners/retroarch/
2022-09-16 00:20:09,522: Running AMD Mesa driver 22.1.7 on AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT (navi10, LLVM 14.0.6, DRM 3.42, 5.15.0-46-generic) (0x731f)
2022-09-16 00:20:09,523: GPU: 1002:731F 1002:0B36 (amdgpu drivers)
2022-09-16 00:20:09,523: i386 libGL.so.1 missing (needed by opengl)
2022-09-16 00:20:09,523: x86_64 libGL.so.1 missing (needed by opengl)
2022-09-16 00:20:09,523: i386 libvulkan.so.1 missing (needed by vulkan)
2022-09-16 00:20:09,523: x86_64 libvulkan.so.1 missing (needed by vulkan)
2022-09-16 00:20:09,523: i386 libgnutls.so.30 missing (needed by gnutls)
2022-09-16 00:20:09,523: x86_64 libgnutls.so.30 missing (needed by gnutls
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant but there's another user directory in `/home` called `linuxbrew`. I know these libraries are installed as when I run the respective commands to install them, apt tells me they're already present and at their newest version, is it something wrong with my path? It seems like they're there but Lutris just can't find them.

On another note, when I try to run steam it tells me `You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6` this isn't really the issue but I put it here in case it gives insight.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with AMD.

Edit: when I run `sudo find / -iname "libvulkan.so.1"` I get

```
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so.1
/snap/mesa-core20/120/egl/lib/libvulkan.so.1
/snap/plex-desktop/18/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so.1
/snap/plex-desktop/17/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so.1
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so.1
/usr/share/code/libvulkan.so.1
/home/dan/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_64/steam-runtime-heavy/pinned_libs_64/libvulkan.so.1
/home/dan/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_64/steam-runtime-heavy/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so.1
/home/dan/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so.1
/home/dan/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so.1
```

And similar output for the other shared object files that lutris says are missing.

Another thing I had done was `source .env` on a project file and I'm thinking this might have misconfigured my path, maybe I have to reset the vulkan environment variable?

Edit: when I clone lutris and run ./setup.py install it installs everything to /home/linuxbrew now which is not right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was that I had both homebrew and apt installed and they were causing conflicts in path so I removed the prior and things look to be working again, knock on wood.